# Default value mechanism in Lua using metatables

Tags: lua, lua-table

I am writing a couple of functions accepting tables as input parameters. These tables constitute a range of options, which should either be given or inferred from default tables.

Concrete use cases can be found in the unit tests below.

The main question:
**Is the code idiomatic Lua – especially the use of metatables?**

#### Code

```
local defvalue = {}

--[[
    Provides a means to fill a table with default options if they are not
    already present.
    This function is based on meta tables and their __index() function.

    table: Your (input) table.
    defTable: A table containing all default values.
    recursive: A boolean indicating if sub-tables should also be bound to the
               values found in defTable.
--]]
function defvalue.bind_table(table, defTable, recursive)
  local mt = {
    __index = function (table, key)
      return defTable[key]
    end
  }
  setmetatable(table, mt)

  if recursive then
    for key, value in pairs(table) do
      if type(value) == "table" then
        defvalue.bind_table(table[key], defTable[key], true)
      end
    end
  end
end

return defvalue
```

#### Unit tests (using [luaunit](https://github.com/bluebird75/luaunit)):

```
require('luaunit/luaunit')
local defvalue = require('defvalue')

TestDefaultValue = {} -- class
    function TestDefaultValue:testDefaultValue()
        local actualTable = {}
        local defTable = {
            property = "value"
        }
        defvalue.bind_table(actualTable, defTable, false)
        assertEquals(actualTable["property"], "value")
   end

    function TestDefaultValue:testRecursiveValues()
        local actualTable = {
            -- test merging of sub-tables
            secondSubTable = {
            }
        }
        local defTable = {
            subTable = {
                property = "value"
            };
            secondSubTable = {
                secondSubProperty = "secondSubValue"
            }
        }
        defvalue.bind_table(actualTable, defTable, true)
        assertEquals(actualTable["subTable"]["property"], "value")
        assertEquals(actualTable["secondSubTable"]["secondSubProperty"], "secondSubValue")
    end

    function TestDefaultValue:testNonRecursiveValues()
        local actualTable = {
            subTable = {}
        }
        local defTable = {
            subTable = {
                property = "Hello World!"
            }
        }

        defvalue.bind_table(actualTable, defTable, false)
        assertEquals(actualTable["subTable"]["property"], nil)
    end

    function TestDefaultValue:testDynamicChange()
        local actualTable = {}
        local defTable = {}

        defvalue.bind_table(actualTable, defTable, false)
        assertEquals(actualTable["property"], nil)

        defTable["property"] = 42
        assertEquals(actualTable["property"], 42)
    end

    function TestDefaultValue:testPropertyShadowing()
        local actualTable = {
            property = "value";
            subTable = {
                subProperty = "subValue"
            };
            secondSubTable = {
                secondSubProperty = "secondSubValue"
            }
        }
        local defTable = {
            property = "hello";
            subTable = {
                subProperty = "world"
            };
            secondSubTable = 42
        }

        defvalue.bind_table(actualTable, defTable, true)
        assertEquals(actualTable["property"], "value")
        assertEquals(actualTable["subTable"]["subProperty"], "subValue")
        assertEquals(actualTable["secondSubTable"]["secondSubProperty"], "secondSubValue")
    end

-- class TestDefaultValue

LuaUnit:run()
```

Comment: You can pass `value` instead of `table[key]` in `defvalue.bind_table(table[key]`

Comment: Also, `table` is a reserved keyword in Lua. Use some other variable name instead :)

Comment: Technically `table` is simply a default module/global but the same remedy is correct. =)

Comment: It might be good to test that `defTable[key]` is a table in that `recursive` loop too. If it isn't the lookup for a default value later might error.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Thanks for the suggestions. Both are now incorporated. Add these as an answer if you would like.

Comment: @EtanReisner There is the possibility of having an option which is either an object or a string. Maybe I should a further boolean paramter to `bind_table`: `allowObjectTypeChanging`.

Comment: Not sure I followed that but yes, a string would also work for as defTable[key] since they can be indexed (not that it'll get you too much). So can custom userdata for that matter.

Comment: @EtanReisner Have a look at `testPropertyShadowing()` above. If one doesn't provide `secondSubTable`, the default value mechanism will provide a default value, which happens to be `42` in this case. The question is whether it makes sense to have an integer as a default value for an attribute, which is normally provided as an object. Allowing such changes would probably introduce unnecessary IF clauses in the code ("if not object, create a new one and incorporate the given integer") and therefore defeat the purpose of a default value mechanism.

Comment: If you comment out `secondSubTable` from `actualTable` in that test and run it you get an error because you cannot index a number value. That was my point.

Comment: @EtanReisner Now I understand you, thanks! An exception is now thrown if the default value is not an object for an object in the actual table. I'd +1 you as well if you provide an answer.

Comment: Right, you assume you can index the default replacement value but that may not be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you comment out `secondSubTable` from `actualTable` in the `testPropertyShadowing` test and run it you get an error because you cannot index a number value.

The problem is that you are assuming that the replacement value will be index-able but not all values are. Tables, strings and custom userdata can be indexed but functions, numbers, and nil (by default at least) cannot be.

You might want to consider checking for the default being a table (testing for userdata requires trying it in a `pcall` I believe and is probably not worth it). Alternatively, you could leave it alone and let people use anything they can index and keep both parts if they use something else.